# How to decode HTML entities while using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm saving some text into my database from a text editor.

Which looks like this in the DB:-

```
<p>Some text blah blah blah</p><br><p>Some more text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p><br><p>And even more text blah blah</p>
```

When I echo the the text in PHP, I just get the result above. How can i get it to use the HTML markup, instead of just printing it. For example, a `'< br >'` tag should create a line break instead of just printing it.

Thanks!

Comment: Question is _why_ the markup is shown like that. This is not the default, so there has to be a reason. Please add more details and code to your question. Specifically it makes sense to shown _how_ you output that content.

Comment: @arkascha I use TinyMCE to write the text, this is then saved into the DB with data type TEXT. I then query the DB to return an array and simply echo the text.

Comment: can you try `html_entity_decode`. If that works your string is saved in the database as encoded html. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_html_entity_decode.asp

Comment: That will not lead to the described behavior. Something else must come in here.

Comment: Any text editor like tinyMCE will produce html in the output. So this will be saved regardless (which i want). However, should PHP realise the HTML markup or does it just ignore and print it as text?

Comment: PHP does not care what the text is. It prints whatever it is. Use `var_dump` to look what the variable has. Also look at the response headers, specifically `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Use `html_entity_decode()`:-***

```
<?php

$string = '<p>Some text blah blah blah</p><br><p>Some more text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p><br><p>And even more text blah blah</p>';

echo html_entity_decode($string);
```

***Output on my local screen:-***

[image]

Comment: Thats the one! Thank you sir!

Comment: @Brian  glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that a wring header is output. Try adding:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Also, you can try to wrap the HTML in < html > tags.

Or maybe something adds < pre > tags around your HTML code. You should try to check the source of your output.

Answer (score 0):

Before storing it into your database use html entity encode and when you retreive the data from the database use html entity decode. it should work